# Is there an easy way to see the Top 100 Global Websites based on monthly uniques?

Tags: traffic, quantcast

I can easily see the top 100 sites on Quantcast, or most of their competitors, but they're based on US uniques.

Now, Quantcast provides Top Lists for non-US Visitors, but they're country by country, so I'd have to dump the Top list from each country and sum them, which isn't practical.  Is there some other way to get the top X sites based on global uniques?

Comment: What is it you plan to do with this information out of interest?

Comment: @bybe, the same thing I do every night... *take over the world*.   Just kidding. While I know it's a vanity metric, and I don't care that much, I'm sometimes asked for my site's ranking.  We know it for the US, but we're more global than a lot of companies, so our global rank is likely different.

Answer (score 2):

There's no easy way to get this data.
First of all you need to realize that you never will get a true top-100 of global websites by unique visitors simply because there's no system measuring everyone in the world. ;)

Google [offers it's top-1000 ranking](http://www.google.com/adplanner/static/top1000/). But that's just google, so you miss nearly whole Asia.

Alexa offers [top sites](http://www.alexa.com/topsites) which are gathered by Alexa toolbar users - these are mostly in US and Europe, but offer far more accurate data with more insight into each website (eg. you can see how viewers of sites differ from global average).

How you can get this data is by using [web scraping](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_scraping) - sadly there's no easy way to obtain these rankings that I'd know of.